# Mount And Blade Warband Will not run on Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: drivers, ati, games, steam, crash

Like I have said above whenever I try to start Mount And Blade Warband (From Steam) It says "Preparing to Launch" for a few seconds and then shuts off. My friend who is running another Linux distro (Not Ubuntu) can run the game fine. Looking for any solutions to this. It only happens for this game. I am using x64 
Here are my specs:
CPU: AMD FX6300 (Default Clock)
GPU: AMD R9 270X with 2GB of VRAM (Default Clock)
RAM: 8GB of G. Skill

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the Game does not have execute permissions set.

In terminal go into the games directory

```
cd  ~/.steam/steamapps/common/"MountBlade Warband" #your path may be different
```

Then change the permissions with this command.

```
sudo chmod u+wrx mb_warband_linux
```

If that dose not work you may need to [Verify Integrity of Game Cache](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=2037-QEUH-3335)

Hope this helps.